# download CSV using filtered dataframe RShiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, shinymodules

I've made an shiny app where I'm filtering a dataset using some values and then I would like to be able to download that filtered dataset. However, I'm struggling to understand how I can pass the filtered dataset to the csv downloader. It is a very large dataset so can't use the buttons available in renderDataTable (I think?) Does anyone have any ideas of how I can do this?

Example app:

```
### data ###
egDf <- data.frame(col1 = sample(letters,10000,replace=T), col2 = sample(letters,10000, replace=T))

### modules ###
chooseCol1UI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns('chooserCol1'))
}
chooseCol1 <- function(input, output, session, data){
  output$chooserCol1 <- renderUI({
    ns <- session$ns
    pickerInput(inputId = ns('chosenCol1'),
              label = 'Col1',
              choices = paste(sort(unique(egDf$col1))),
              options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
              multiple = TRUE)
  })

  return(reactive(input$chosenCol1))

}

csvDownloadUI <- function(id, label = "Download CSV") {
  ns <- NS(id)
  downloadButton(ns("downloadData"), label)
}
csvDownload <- function(input, output, session, data) {
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(names(data), Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep='')
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(data, file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
}

displayTableUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  DT::dataTableOutput(ns('displayer'))
}
displayTable <- function(input, output, session, data, col1Input){
  output$displayer <- DT::renderDataTable(egDf %>% filter(col1 %in% col1Input()))
}

### server ###
server <- function(input,output){
  chosenCol1 <- callModule(chooseCol1,
                               id = 'appChooseCol1', data = egDf)
  callModule(module = displayTable, id = "appDisplayTable",
             col1Input = chosenCol1)
}

### ui ###
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
  chooseCol1UI("appChooseCol1")),
mainPanel(displayTableUI("appDisplayTable")))

### app ###
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Basically, you're asking how to use download buttons in shiny. Save your data in a variable and pass it to `downloadHandler()`. See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45236368/how-to-use-the-download-button-in-shiny), run example app from R: `runExample("10_download")`

Comment: I think the question is more about how to get the filtered data from the displayTable - right?

Comment: @ill exactly, that's what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few years ago I made an app with such a button. In my case I created a reactive expression in the `server.R` file that is being passed to the `downloadHandler`.

Here's [the app](http://thelab.alessiobenedetti.com/shiny/uCountVis/) and here's [the github code](https://github.com/abenedetti/uCountVisualizer). Head to the `server.R` file and search for the "download" string.

In the app you'll find a blue download button in the "Data" tab. The app let's you apply filters that applies in the datatable, that you can download via the button.

***Edit:*** here's the server portion of code of interest:

```
#data download button
   output$idDwn <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { 
     paste('uCount ', format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S"), '.csv', sep='')
    },
    content = function(file) {
     write.csv(datasetInputFilters(), file)
    }
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create `eventReactive` function that allows your `col1Input`.

```
  # Reactive function based on input
  react_df <- eventReactive(input$chosenCol1, {

    return(egDf %>% filter(col1 %in% input$chosenCol1))

  })

  output$displayer <- renderDataTable(react_df())

  # Download box
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {

      output_d <- react_df()

      write.csv(output_d, file, row.names = FALSE)

    }
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with this issue recently and unfortunately that solution didn't work for me. But simply using `writexl::write_xlsx()` instead of `write.csv()` was enough.